# Extract Java comments from SQL statement in R

Tags: r

Trying to run a SQL statement in an RStudio environment, but I'm having difficulty extracting Java-style comments from the statement. I cannot edit the SQL statements / comments themselves, so trying a sequence of `gsub` to remove the unwanted special characters so I'm left with only the SQL statement in the R string.

I'm trying to use `gsub` to remove the special characters and the comment in between, but struggling to find the right regex to do so (especially one that does not read the division symbol in the SELECT statement as a part of the Java comment).

```
SELECT
      id
    , metric
    , SUM(numerator)/SUM(denominator) AS rate
/*
This is an example of the comment.
I want to remove this. */
FROM table
WHERE id = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove anything between `/*` and `*/` using this regex:

```
gsub(pattern = "/\\*[^*]*\\*/", replacement = "", x = text)
```

Result:

```
"SELECT\n      id\n, metric\n, SUM(numerator)/SUM(denominator) AS rate\n/\nFROM table\nWHERE id = 2"
```